# "Initialize Push Notifications" Push Notifications for Wordpress

Tags: android, wordpress, notifications, push, builder

I've been studying projects made in Android Studio for a few months, these days I've been trying to implement the "Push Notifications for Wordpress" plugin on a website, with the addition of the library provided by delitestudio.com for the android application. I'm following these instructions: https://www.delitestudio.com/wordpress/push-notifications-for-wordpress/push-notifications-library-for-android/

But as I do not have much experience, I do not know where to add this instruction:

```
Initialize Push Notifications

    Add the following calls using the PushNotifications.Builder to initialize the library with your site’s url:

    public class MyApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new PushNotifications.Builder(this, "http://[YOUR WORDPRESS SERVER]")
          .build();
      }
    }
```

And several others for the text onwards, i did some research but I have not been able to understand it, I know it's too much to ask someone to teach me step by step, but I ask that someone with more experience enlighten me by giving at least the path where I should insert the instructions (if it should be inserted in mainactivity, Build.gradle, etc, for example) given in the link that I posted, since in the site quoted do not explain in detail. If you can help me by giving this path, I will be grateful, giving the other paths after this one, it would be even better. But thank you in advance for the help, forgive my English.